# How to disable PictureInPicture in shaka player

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, video-player, shaka

I am using shaka player to play video,
I am getting picture in picture option on menu items along with quality, language and playback speed

I want to disable picture in picture from list

I tried to add `disablePictureInPicture` in video player but still getting PIP

```
  <video
        className="w-full h-full"
        data-testid="video-element"
        ref={videoRef}
        poster={posterUrl}
        autoPlay
        disablePictureInPicture
      ></video>
```

I tried to add custom configuration as well

```
 player.configure({
      abr: { enabled: true},
      streaming: {
        rebufferingGoal: 5,
        bufferBehind: 10*60,
        bufferingGoal: 30,
        failureCallback: failureCallbackHandler
      },
      'overflowMenuButtons' : ['quality','language','playback_rate']
    });
```

Still seeing PIP in UI

Also tried using native video player element

```
 videoRef.current.setAttribute('disablepictureinpicture', 'true');
      videoRef.current.disablePictureInPicture = true
```

Still seeing PictureInPicture  video player
Is there a way to disable PictureInPicture  in shaka player

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug when disabling PiP on shaka player https://github.com/shaka-project/shaka-player/pull/5992

We can use UI configuration to configure

```
ui.configure({
   'overflowMenuButtons' : ['quality','language','playback_rate']
});
```